# Is it possible to use nonfree WiFi drivers in a live environment?

Tags: wireless, 23.04

I am trying to use a live ISO of Ubuntu 23.04 on a laptop that requires proprietary WiFi drivers. My networking card is detected correctly in Software Center and I am able to enable the proprietary drivers, but I still don't have any WiFi networks showing up in my network settings. Normally, you have to reboot after installing the proprietary drivers in order for the desktop environment to detect them, but I cannot do this because I am in a live environment.

**Is it possible to use nonfree WiFi drivers in a live environment?** E.g. is there a systemd command I can use to prompt the system to rescan for WiFi hardware?

Comment: If you can load them (`insmod` or insert module into kernel) you may find a simple GUI logout & login may recognize them; have you tried?

Comment: Logging out and back in doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: How about unloading and reloading the driver: `sudo modprobe -r <driver> && sudo modprobe <driver>` or restarting Network Manager: `sudo service NetworkManager restart` or this: `nmcli device wifi rescan`

Comment: @chili555 None of these suggestions worked, unfortunately. The first two execute but don't produce any output or change; the third gives an error saying no WiFi device is present. (I know that the proprietary broadcom drivers work, in general, on this hardware because I have used them in other Linux distros.)

Comment: Let's have a look at: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Which driver did you install?

Comment: Driver installed is `broadcom-sta-dkms`. Output of your command lists the Broadcom network controller and says `Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge`

Comment: In order to learn if broadcom-sta-dkms is correct for your device, we need to know the *exact* details of your card. "Broadcom network controller" could be any of dozens of devices. Not all use the driver you installed. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395

Comment: The PCI ID is `14e4:4331` and the firmware listed in the thread you linked is `firmware-b43-installer`. I really doubt that Ubuntu is installing the wrong firmware because this is a very common chip and laptop (a Macbook Pro 9,2 which has worked fine with previous versions of Ubuntu when installing on bare metal). I just need a way to tell Gnome to refresh its menus now that the firmware has been enabled, which one would normally accomplish by rebooting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145832/discussion-between-chili555-and-max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install software, drivers, firmware, etc. in a live environment.

First, install the probable correct driver and remove the incorrect driver:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Unload and reload the driver to get the driver *b43* to recognize and use the newly installed firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you. A point of emphasis is that for whatever reason, the proprietary drivers that Ubuntu tries to install for you are not the right ones for the chipset on some models. This is why that [installing Broadcom wireless drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1) megapost exists.